# Excel: Loop does not execute all the motions even if there is a value

Tags: excel, vba

First of all thanks for fixing my first problem. However, when trying to execute the formula/loop, it immediately goes to `end if` after `if score > "0"`, even if the score actually is bigger than 0 (for example 64).

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim score As Integer, sStart As Integer, sTeller As Integer, _
                          lcount As Integer, result As String
    sStart = Sheets("Packed").Range("F1").Value
    sTeller = Sheets("Packed").Range("E1").Value
    lcount = sStart
    score = Range("B" & lcount).Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While lcount < sTeller
    Sheets("Packed").Select
    If score > "0" Then 'HERE!
      Range("A" & lcount & ":C" & lcount).Select
      Selection.Cut
      Sheets("data").Select
      Range("A5").Select
      Selection.End(xlDown).Select
      Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste    
    End If
    lcount = lcount + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "All values have been checked"

    Columns("D:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried **If score > 0 Then**?  "0" is text - 0 (without quotes) is a number.

Edit: Just tried it with a value and it worked with score = "8", so ignore that comment.

Comment: What is in `Sheets("Packed").Range("F1").Value`?

Comment: Is the 'Packed' sheet active as **score = Range("B" & lcount).Value** may be getting it's value from the wrong sheet - no sheet is specified.

Comment: In **sheets("packed").range("f1").value** is the number 5 (since the values start at cell "b5"). 
In **code'sheets("packed").range("e1").value** is the amount of entries in column A+4 (since the values start at cell "5").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when trying to execute the formula/loop, it immediately goes to "end if" after "if score > "0"", even if the score actually is bigger than 0

this is because of you set `score = Range("B" & lcount).Value` only once before loop, and `score` has not been updated each time when `lcount` moved through the loop. so, put `score = Range("B" & lcount).Value` inside loop

here your updated code

```
Sub whatever()
Dim score As Integer, sStart As Integer, sTeller As Integer, lcount As Integer, result As String
sStart = Sheets("Packed").Range("F1").Value
sTeller = Sheets("Packed").Range("E1").Value
lcount = sStart

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While lcount < sTeller
    Sheets("Packed").Activate
    score = Range("B" & lcount).Value
    If score > 0 Then
        Range("A" & lcount & ":C" & lcount).Cut
        Sheets("data").Activate
        Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Paste
    End If
    lcount = lcount + 1
Loop

MsgBox "All values have been checked"

Columns("D:F").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

and only by the reason that I saw that score updated only once before the loop, i suggested you do not use loop in previous your question.

Answer (score 0):

**This is incorrect**

`if score > "0" Then`

**This is correct:**

`if score > 0 Then`

Comment: Although the first example is technically incorrect both version will work as shown in my comment to the OP.

Comment: Specifically, because VBA tries (and succeed) to convert the "0" since the ">" is a numerical operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

```
Sub WhatEver()

    Dim score As Integer
    Dim sStart As Integer
    Dim sTeller As Integer
    Dim lcount As Integer
    Dim result As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Packed")

        sStart = .Cells(1, 6)
        sTeller = .Cells(1, 5)
        lcount = sStart
        score = .Cells(lcount, 2)

        Do While lcount < sTeller
            If score > 0 Then
                .Range(.Cells(lcount, 1), .Cells(lcount, 3)).Cut _
                    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown)
            End If
            lcount = lcount + 1
        Loop

        MsgBox "All values have been checked."
        .Columns("D:F").Delete shift:=xlToLeft

    End With

End Sub
```